# Passing data across tabs in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Trying to pass data between tabs in a UITab Controller . 
I've tried using delegates and couldn't get it to work , and also tried instantiating an object of the class to pass the data to it, and couldn't get that working as well.

my setup is like this ...
[image]

Im trying to send data from the test table to the favourites table as shown by the arrows...
as I'm trying to implement a favourites table view controller for the user to favourite table cells he likes .

Comment: Your best bet is to use core data since your favorites will not be temporary

Comment: any example of how to pass info from the tableView to the to core data file and then transfer that to the favourites table view?

Comment: yes there are tutorials out there you're going to have to build it ground up. Create the entities etc. Just google it or read the apple docs. http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

Comment: CoreData is pretty heavy and if you only need to hold on to simple data it may not be required.

Comment: @Paul.s would you have a simpler method to store the data rather then using coreData because it seems that the app I'm creating doesn't require coreData because its a very simple app .

Comment: If your data needs a simple you can look at NSUserDefaults or just plist serialisation to start.

Comment: @stringRay2014 Paul is correct, CoreData is heavy, but it's relatively simple to use, flexible, easier than sqlite and has built in features built out of the box like sectionnamekeypath, loading a certain number of cells at a time instead of the whole plist file (which can be slow and cumbersome when you have over 500+ favorites) and more. This will also make it easier for you as your app changes through the years. Don't be scared to dabble in CoreData, it's not hard to implement at all. However, there is nothing wrong with Plists either. Can't go wrong with either option

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Core Data aswell but if you find it too difficult for your project you can use Plist files for your favorites.

Note that this is a quick example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([favorites containsObject:items[indexPath.row]]) {
        [favorites removeObjectAtIndex:[favorites indexOfObject:items[indexPath.row]]];
    }
    else {
        [favorites addObject:items[indexPath.row]];
    }
    [self saveItems];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)loadItems {
    NSString *filePath = [self pathForItems];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        favorites = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
    } else {
        favorites = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}

- (void)saveItems {

    NSString *filePath = [self pathForItems];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:favorites toFile:filePath];
}

- (NSString *)pathForItems {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [paths lastObject];

    return [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorites.plist"];
}
```